# Azure DevOps Release pipeline is wrongly creating a HTTP Redirect in IIS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps Release pipeline to deploy my .NET application code to the IIS on a windows server. For this, I am using the

```
    steps:
  - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy IIS QA'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: my.site.name
    Package: ' $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    XmlVariableSubstitution: true
```

For some reason, every time I do this deployment, the http redirect setting gets added, which I don't want. I am not able to find any setting in the pipeline which is enforcing this. See the images below.

**Before**

[image]

**After**
[image]

**Following is the security header I have in my web.config file**

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147482624" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Http to Https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

It turns out this session is not coming from the pipeline, but from the higher-level site (global variables) in the IIS itself.

When I removed this from the highest level possible, the issue got resolved.